# Event Grid with communication with 2 microservices

Tags: azure-eventgrid

We are trying to achieve event-based communication between 2 microservices 
Currently we have created 2 microservices with .Net Core.

1. Email Service
   http://xxxx.demoemailserviceapi.azurewebsites.net/swagger
2. Product Service 
   http://yyyy.azurewebsites.net/swagger

We have created Event Grid to handle the communication between them. When we try to add endpoints to eventgrid and proceed with deployment then we are getting error as follows

> Deployment has failed with the following error: {"code":"Url validation","message":"The attempt to validate the provided endpoint https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/EventGrid failed. For more details, visit https://aka.ms/esvalidation."}

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I do recommend to read the following documents:

[Event Grid trigger for Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-grid)

[Event Grid security and authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/security-authentication)

Note, that the endpoint url of the EventGridTrigger function has the format:

```
https://{functionappname}.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/eventgrid?functionName={functionname}&code={systemkey}
```